# Letters and envelopes: what is the probability that exactly $2$ letters will be placed in the correct envelopes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

If $\mathrm n$ letters are placed at random in $\mathrm n$ envelopes, what is the probability that exactly $\text{2}$ letters will be placed in the correct envelopes?

I know the solution about this question.

Step 1:

The probability of at least one letter will be placed
in the correct envelope is 
$$\mathrm P_n = 1 - \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots + (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n!}$$

Step 2:

The probability of exact $2$ envelopes are matching means other $\mathrm n-2$ envelops are mismatching.

If we select $2$ from $n$ envelopes, we have $\mathrm{C_{n}^{2}}$ choices. For each choice, we have $(1 - \mathrm P_{n-2}) \cdot (n-2)! $ events that all other envelopes are mismatching.
\begin{align}
P(\text{exact 2 envelopes matching}) &= \frac{\# \text{Events that exact 2 matching}}{\# \text{All Events}}\\
& = \frac{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}(n-2)![1 - (\mathrm P_{n-2})]}{n!}\\
& = \frac{1}{2}[\frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots + (-1)^{n-2}\frac{1}{(n-2)!} ]
\end{align}

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Add my solution. But I wanna know any other idea.

Comment: For exactly 2 matches, I think this is the right approach.

Comment: Check derangement - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements